# how does one add a subscription to a folder on Google Reader procedurally (thru the API)?

Tags: google-reader

I want to manage a Google Reader "folder" of feeds that I can add and subtract feeds to programatically. I presume that's possible but I can't seem to find any API documentation on that subject. Any advice?
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public API isn't available yet unfortunately... I am eagerly awaiting it myself.

I know there is an unofficial version [documented](http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI) but it is outdated anyways.